Helm Chart: wordpress deployment problem to reach RDS
I'm not able to deploy Wordpress using ArgoCD and bitnami/wordpress Helm Chart.
I have set the following values
mariadb:
  enabled: false

externalDatabase:
  host: rds-aws-address.com
  user: <user>
  database: WordpressDB
  port: 3306
  existingSecret: wordpress-externaldb-password

Enabling debugging shows the following in the pod logs

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'wordpress-mariadb'

I can't find anywhere where wordpress-mariadb is set
I have spun up an sql pod to check network and dns resolution and I was able to connect fine.
Everything else seems fine
Information
K8 on EKS v1.30
Wordpress Helm Chart:
- name: wordpress
  version: "23.0.11"
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami


What happens if you run helm template for that chart with the provided input values? When I do so, I cannot find any reference to the value wordpress-mariadb in the emitted configuration: helm template --version 23.0.11 test bitnami/wordpress -f values.yaml | grep wordpress-mariadb

I don't get anything there either
Although when looking at the env vars I see this, where I expect my values
        `- name: MARIADB_HOST`
          `value: "test-mariadb"`
        `- name: MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER`
          `value: "3306"`
        `- name: WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME`
          `value: "bitnami_wordpress"`
        `- name: WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER`
          `value: "bn_wordpress"`


Is this a clean installation or an existing database? I also suggest inspecting the objects in your Kubernetes cluster directly, especially the deployment, to validate what ArgoCD is applying.

It's a clean mysql database in RDS
Checking the deployment with kubectl describe deployment wordpress shows my that the env vars are as I expect with the values passed in from the values.yaml file as described above

To update on this - I built my own wordpress manifest linking to RDS and everything is working fine. I suspect it's something in the bitnami wordpress helm chart
